# Braintree Webhook Destination is not verified

Tags: .net, gateway, braintree

I want braintree webhook notifications on my website. For this I have tried lot to set up webhook at my sandbox account But I am unable to set up as It is showing error "Destination could not be verified"But not succeeded. Please suggest what is wrong . Should I have to pass any specific string to "bt_challenge" parameter ? I have tried with:

1. `domain/controller/Action`
2. `domain/controller/Action?bt_challenge=`

Comment: Hey Kulbir, you haven't really provided enough information here to diagnose the problem. I'd suggest you reach out to [Braintree's support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/). It would also be nice if you'd upvote / accept answers to the other questions you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you need more help, please [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Take a look at the [.NET Webhook Notification Tutorial](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/dotnet/guide/webhook_notifications) and [.NET Webhook Notification Docs](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/dotnet/webhooks/overview).

A brief example from the webhook tutorial, building on the examples from the other tutorials:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Braintree;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace braintree_tutorial.Controllers
{
    public class WebhooksController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Accept()
        {
          return Content(Constants.Gateway.WebhookNotification.Verify(Request.QueryString["bt_challenge"]));
        }
    }
}
```

And as far as what URL to enter:

> If our site were hosted at `http://www.example.com`, we would enter `http://www.example.com/webhooks/accept` as the Webhook destination URL. This matches the new route we setup in step one.

So `domain/controller/action` should be correct.

Comment: @KulbirSingh Please get in touch with the Braintree support team; the best way is to email them at support@braintreepayments.com. They can look up your information in our logs and see what the specific problem is.

Comment: sorry I havn't up yur answer because your code wasn't help to solve my problem, I said to thanks for your suggestion to contact support team. I am doing answer up for suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to configure braintree to work with development (i.e localhost) is on this link. I also struggled with this but found a solution

[How to configure braintree webhooks for localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755309/how-to-configure-braintree-webhooks-for-localhost)